# Appsheet : open a form and insert the name of company in a field

Tags: google-appsheet

I'm starting with appssheet.
I have a table "Company" and "Actions"
From Company form, I want to open a form in "Action table" (it's ok)
But I want to fill the company name in the field "Company" in the form. To avoid searching the company in the scrolling menu on the form.

Do you have something for me ?
Thanks a lot.
Laurent

I succed to use : "LINKTOVIEW("Interventions_Form")" to acces a new form to create a new action...
But a can't add the company name in the field "Company" in the form.[screen capture of the form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v26d7.png)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using LINKTOVIEW(), you should try LINKTOFORM(). This function gives you the ability to pass some values. For example:

```
LINKTOFORM(form view name, column, value)
LINKTOFORM(„Interventions_Form“, „Company“, [Company Name])
```

This will open up the form „Interventions_Form“ and adds the Company Name to the column Company.

More informations can be found here: https://support.google.com/appsheet/answer/10106538?hl=en